# ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode() in Test causes Warning

Tags: reactjs

I built my application wir create-react-app. In the recent version of it, it adds one line in the bootstrapped test setup in Jest to unmount the component (see `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div)`).

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

It causes a warning when I run the test for my App component.

**Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.**

My guess: It happens because I have an asynchronous request in `componentDidMount()`:

```
fetchFoo(bar) {
  fetch(SOME_URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => this.setState({ result }))
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error }));
}
```

If this is the case, how do I wait in the test for the asynchronous request to finally unmount the component again? I know that I could remove the one liner in the Jest test which causes this, but rather I would like to fix it.

- [Here you can find the issue](https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/the-road-to-learn-react/issues/101).

**SOLUOTION:** Solved it and documented how to solve it over [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-warning-cant-call-setstate-on-an-unmounted-component/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to resolve this issue is to make your `fetch()` properly cancel itself when the component is unmounted. Having async requests in a `componentDidMount()` *that don't cancel themselves* is bad practice in React, because depending on network speed and UI interactions, they can frequently attempt to update the state of an unmounted component. Either use a cancelable `Promise`, or use a `this.shouldCancel` instance variable to indicate weather to call `setState()` or not, like so:

```
class LifecycleTest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.shouldCancel = false;
    this.state = {
      result:null,
      err:null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    asyncTask()
      .then(result => !this.shouldCancel ? this.setState({result}) : null)
      .catch(err => !this.shouldCancel ? this.setState({err}) : null);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.shouldCancel = true
  }

  render(){
    const {err, result} = this.state
    if(err){
      return <div className="err">{err}</div>
    }else if (result){
      return <div className="result">{result}</div>
    }else{
      return <div className="loading">Loading...</div>
    }        
  }
}
```

([view on webpackbin](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-L54VyeaHRmv4M36ZO1C))

That said, if you really want to make this test pass without changing the source, you could mock `fetch()` to return a 'dud' `Promise` that never resolves. For instance, adding this should fix the error:

```
window.fetch = jest.fn(() => new Promise((accept, reject) => {}))
```

However, this is a dreadful hack. The better solution is just to properly cancel network requests on component unmount.

Comment: Great explanation and you convinced me that the source code needs to be touched again. Could you add an example to cancel the network request on component unmount?

Comment: Just added the example. Cancelable promises right now are a bit janky, it's definitely more clear to use `this.shouldCancel`.

Answer (score 2):

You can see in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) that `componentDidMount()` is the recommended location for handling network requests.

The reason you're getting this error, is that you're using `setState` in an asynchronous call that isn't bound by React's lifecycle, so you end up attempting to setState well after the component has been un-mounted.

Your opportunity to handle/correct this would be in `componentWillUnmount()`. This would require crafting your `fetch()` request to somehow be cancelled during the `componentWillUnmount()` method. You need to wrap your network requests in a cancellable promise to be able to do this, since `fetch()` doesn't natively support directly cancelling the request.

Ultimately, this would prevent the `setState()` from being called *after* you have unmounted the component.